# Solvability of finite groups of order coprime to 15 -- proof without using CFSG?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is the solvability of finite groups of order coprime to 15
essentially easier to prove than the entire Classification of Finite Simple Groups?

Comment: Can you use Thompson's N-groups http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-group_(finite_group_theory) ?

Comment: The answer is yes, because Thompson proved that the only finite simple groups of order coprime to 3 are the Suzuki groups, and Glauberman later extended this to a classification of simple groups that do not have $S_3$ as a subgroup. Bothe of thsoe results are pre-classification. But I have a suspicion that neither of them was ever published!

Comment: @Derek, Mark: Thank you very much! (The result would follow also from the classification of minimal simple groups (Thompson, 1968) if one knows that every nonabelian finite simple group contains a minimal simple group, but is there a proof of the latter which is not based on CFSG? -- Barry and Ward (http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/PUBLICACIONSMATEMATIQUES_1997_41_02_07.pdf) write "It is a consequence of the classification of finite simple groups that every non-abelian simple group contains a subgroup which is a minimal simple group".) 


Comment: But what is the meaning of "without CFSG"? For instance does it allow making use of Feit-Thompson? Does Thompson's result about groups of order prime to 3 use Feit-Thompson?

Comment: @Yves: The proof of Feit-Thompson's Odd Order Theorem has something like 200 pages, while even the second-generation classification proof will have about 5000 pages. So I'd say definitely something can still be essentially easier to prove than CFSG if the proof needs Feit-Thompson.

 

Comment: @Derek: Maybe you could turn the nice answer from your comment into an answer which shows up as such? -- I think it is nicer if questions which are completely answered are not shown with '0 answers' ... .


Comment: @Stefan: you're obviously right and I didn't say or suggest the contrary. But CFSG is made up of various sub-results, one of which is Feit-Thompson, which is certainly not the easiest. So it is natural to ask whether a given result makes use of it; more generally it is meaningful to wonder on which part of the classification does a given result rely on; obviously a general consequence of CFSG as you mention will not make use of the full classification. There are also statements not relying on any part of the classification, e.g. that for $G$ nonabelian simple we have $gcd(|g|,4)\neq 2$.

Comment: @StefanKohl Perhaps I am missing something but isn't a minimal counterexample to "Every finite group of order coprime to 15 is solvable" necessarily a minimal simple group? So doesn't this follow from Thompson's N-group result as Mark mentioned?

Comment: @ThomasBrowning Essentially you are right -- just note that it was not *a priori* clear that every finite simple group indeed has a minimal simple subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Derek Holt has pointed out, the answer to the question is *yes*. --
Thompson proved that the only finite simple groups of order coprime to 3 are the
Suzuki groups, and Glauberman later extended this to a classification of
simple groups that do not have ${\rm S}_3$ as a subgroup.
Both of these results are pre-classification, though they might not have been published.

Comment: Taking into account the suggestions on Meta (http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/493/questions-answered-in-a-comment), I have turned Derek's comment into an answer. This is mainly to make clear that the question has already been answered.

Comment: Glauberman's classification of S_4-free groups was definitely published. Also, a simple group of minimal order subject to having order prime to 3 has every proper subgroup solvable, so is an $N$-group, and would appear in Thompson's (published) list of $N$-groups, so the answer is yes on the basis of published results.

Comment: @Geoff: Thanks for your remark! -- By the way, is it possible that you rather mean ${\rm S}_3$-free groups than ${\rm S}_4$-free ones?

Comment: No, I meant what I sai. I think Glauberman published an AMS Monograph on S_4-free group. Clearly, an S_3-free group is S_4 free, so Glauberman's S_4-free classification includes the classification of S_3-free groups.